# Reverse multiple transactions Google Management API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am looking at refunds and reserving transactions in Google Enhanced Ecommerce. Using the Management API you can do it for refunds - full or partial but with reversing a transaction the only example it by a "hit" i.e loading another confirmation page.

The business that I am looking into it for have a lot of price changes because they use an auction based system. Do you know if there is a way of reversing the transaction to add negative value to an existing transaction ID to reduce the price but do this on a bigger scale.

It is easy to do one transaction [one transaction](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1037443?hl=en) but if you wanted to automate the process is there a way of doing it through the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Management API is for account management (i.e. setting up properties and views, configuring filters, addding and removing users etc). So the Management API is not what you are looking for. To retrieve information on your transactions you would use the [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/). To send transactions you'd have to use the "data collection API", or as it is called by its proper name the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) which would allow to send hits (including transactions) programmatically.

However you should not try to reverse transactions by sending negative transactions.

If you send another transaction with the same ID it will not actually reverse the transaction, instead its transaction value will be added to the first one, so if you send a negative value the values will cancel each other out.

However internally they are still recorded as two transactions, which has several consequences:

- your conversion rate will be off
- transactions values cancel each other out only if both transactions are within the same reporting timeframe
- you need to take care that both transaction are attributed to the same channel, else you cannot properly report revenue per channel (and if you optimize bidding or created audiences based on revenue you have just wrecked your marketing)

So do not reverse transactions. Use refunds, despite their apparent shortcomings.

Comment: Mind adding some links to the reporting api and the measurement protocol for him so he understands how to do it programmatically and I will delete my answer.

Comment: The problem with the refunds is it is for everything or one product. Most of the time our "refunds" are price changes. So they checkout for £100 but it changes to £50. The refund system does not allow just price changes does it?

Comment: The documentation does not mention price changes - but then the upload csv scheme has a column for product price which would be pointless if the upload would not take the price into account. I guess it's time for a little experiment.... But in the meantime I'm afraid you do not really have any good options, as not matter what you do you will have some skewed metrics.

Comment: @DaImTo, I edited in a paragraph about the relevant APIs. Think this will do ?

Comment: yup, perfect there is no good solution for this but at least we are covering all the bases :)

Comment: I did think it would not be simple ha! I'd be happy if I can just get the revenue as close as it should be. At the moment it can be very skewed because the auction style and combinations can change the price so drastically. Just trying to find a way of getting more accurate reporting, we have some internal reports but the IT team are not the greatest at making things "useable"

Comment: Maybe you could break down your purchases into smaller units (i.e. do not record a quantity one for a product at 100$ but a quantity of 10 for 10$). Then you can do partial refunds to arrive at least broadly in the vicinity of the correct total (no idea if this is feasible for you, but it is currently my only idea).